# Create class from string

Tags: c#, class, reflection, activator

I'm trying to create a class from its name held in a string. I've tried a bunch of things but always get "Value cannot be null"

Here's the class

```
public static readonly MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Color Aquamarine
Member of MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Colors
```

**AquaMarine** is a class held in MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Colors and is a class of **Color**

Here's what I tried which is as close as what I thought should work:

```
Color myColor = (Color)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Colors+SlateBlue")); 
//+ for nested classes
```

A variant:

```
Color myColor = (Color)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel+Colors+SlateBlue"));
```

But I always get:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
```

I feel like the solution should not be very far... Any ideas ? :)

Comment: I'm not aware of class names allowing `+` in them.

Comment: According to this, yes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Aquamarine` is not a class, it's a variable. You can't create an instance of a variable...

Answer (score 1):

You get the null parameter exception because `Type.GetType()` returns null. 
What you specified as argument for `Type.GetType()` is a Field name, not a type name. The type name would be `"MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Color"`.

If you want the field named `SlateBlue` from that type, you would need to use [`GetField()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee) on the type that contains the colors.

I think you are confusing type (class/struct) and instance here. `Aquamarine` contains an *instance* of the type `Color`. That is not the same as the type itself.

Comment: Well, actually it's not even an instance of the class, it's just a variable that holds a reference to an instance of the class.

Comment: @Guffa Usually yes, but [`MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Color`](http://gitorious.org/pdfsharp/pdfsharp/blobs/eeff3cf38c18525af8bed2e44df76af38294a956/MigraDoc/code/MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel/MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel/Color.cs) is a ValueType.